# Wrapping an iOS UILabel as a block within a constrained UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout

I have a couple of UILabels within an UIView.

I constrain that containing view to 100px. If both the UILabels have an intrinsic width of 75px each (because of their content) what I would like is that the second label drops below the first because it cannot display without wrapping it's own text.

Is there a containing View in iOS that would support that behaviour?

Comment: You *could* do that with a `UICollectionView`, but that seems like overkill unless you have several instances. Another option would be to check the label widths in code (when you change the text), and position them accordingly.

Comment: I've never used UICollectionView and FlowLayoutlooks interesting but it looks like it is there to flow the "rows" in the set whereas I am trying to flow the "columns" in a row

Comment: Suppose you set a collection view's width to 100... if all the cells are each 20px wide, you will get 4 cells per row. If the First cell is 80px wide, and the 2nd cell is more than 20px wide, the 2nd cell will be placed at the start of the next row.

Comment: Although... if you've never used collection views, I think I'd recommend calculating the sizes. Pretty simple: get width of text in Label-A, get width of text in Label-B, if the sum (plus desired spacing?) is less than 100, put B at same Y as A, and at X at width of A + spacing. If greater than 100, put B at X=0, and Y = height of A ("wrap" to the next line").

Answer (score 0):

Here is one example of "wrapping" labels based on fitting into the width of a parent view.

You can run this directly in a Playground page... Tap the red "Tap Me" button to toggle the text in the labels, to see how they "fit".

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

// String extension for easy text width/height calculations
extension String {
    func height(withConstrainedWidth width: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
        let constraintRect = CGSize(width: width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        let boundingBox = self.boundingRect(with: constraintRect, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [.font: font], context: nil)
        return ceil(boundingBox.height)
    }

    func width(withConstrainedHeight height: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
        let constraintRect = CGSize(width: .greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: height)
        let boundingBox = self.boundingRect(with: constraintRect, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [.font: font], context: nil)
        return ceil(boundingBox.width)
    }
}

class TestViewController : UIViewController {

    let btn: UIButton = {
        let b = UIButton()
        b.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        b.setTitle("Tap Me", for: .normal)
        b.backgroundColor = .red
        return b
    }()

    let cView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .blue
        return v
    }()

    let labelA: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        // we will be explicitly setting the label's frame
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        v.backgroundColor = .yellow
        return v
    }()

    let labelB: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        // we will be explicitly setting the label's frame
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        v.backgroundColor = .cyan
        return v
    }()

    // spacing between labels when both fit on one line
    let spacing: CGFloat = 8.0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(btn)

        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTap(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        btn.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        btn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 20.0).isActive = true

        // add the "containing" view
        view.addSubview(cView)

        // add the two labels to the containing view
        cView.addSubview(labelA)
        cView.addSubview(labelB)

        // constrain containing view Left-20, Top-20 (below the button)
        cView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0).isActive = true
        cView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btn.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0).isActive = true

        // containing view has a fixed width of 100
        cView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0).isActive = true

        // constrain bottom of containing view to bottom of labelB (so the height auto-sizes)
        cView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: labelB.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true

        // initial text in the labels - both will fit "on one line"
        labelA.text = "First"
        labelB.text = "Short"

    }

    func updateLabels() -> Void {
        // get the label height based on its font
        if let h = labelA.text?.height(withConstrainedWidth: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude, font: labelA.font) {
            // get the calculated width of each label
            if let wA = labelA.text?.width(withConstrainedHeight: h, font: labelA.font),
                let wB = labelB.text?.width(withConstrainedHeight: h, font: labelB.font) {

                // labelA frame will always start at 0,0
                labelA.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: wA, height: h)

                // will both labels + spacing fit in the containing view's width?
                if wA + wB + spacing <= cView.frame.size.width {
                    // yes, so place labelB to the right of labelA (put them on "one line")
                    labelB.frame = CGRect(x: wA + spacing, y: 0.0, width: wB, height: h)
                } else {
                    // no, so place labelB below labelA ("wrap" labelB "to the next line")
                    labelB.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: h, width: wB, height: h)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        updateLabels()
    }

    @objc func didTap(_ sender: Any?) -> Void {
        // toggle labelB's text
        if labelB.text == "Short" {
            labelB.text = "Longer text"
        } else {
            labelB.text = "Short"
        }
        // adjust size / position of labels
        updateLabels()
    }

}


let vc = TestViewController()
vc.view.backgroundColor = .white
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = vc
```